# failed to get volume information sccm 2012

Tags: sccm-2012

SCCM 2012 primary site `distmgr.log` throws error - failed to get volume information, it throws failed to get volume information for many Distribution points.

[image]

What kind of root causes would lead to this type of error?

How can I remediate this problem?